# On a work item I've got 2 combos; the 2nd combo's values are dependent on the 1st

Tags: tfs

On a work item I've got 2 combos where the 2nd combo's values are dependent on the 1st.

e.g. The 1st combo has 2 allowedvalues ("vowels", "consonants"), 2nd combo would show a,e,i,o,u if the first was set to vowels etc.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

someting like dis works

```
<FIELD name="Response" refname="Response" type="String" > <!-- values change depending on Category-->
  <WHEN field="Category" value="1">
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="111" />
      <LISTITEM value="1111" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  </WHEN>
  <WHEN field="Category" value="2">
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="222" />
      <LISTITEM value="2222" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  </WHEN>   
</FIELD>
```

While you can do this it does not work with large lists as you can quickly hit the maximum limit for the size of a work item. It is not really a recommended practice.

Comment: "While you can do this it does not work with large lists as you can quickly hit the maximum limit for the size of a work item. It is not really a recommended practice." MrHinsh

Comment: what's the recommended practice? and why are you editing my answer rather than adding comments?